# EF6, DTO, update navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, crud, dto, n-tier-architecture

I am using `Entity Framework 6` with `Generic Repository` and `DTOs`.
I want to create new `entities` via navigation property.
Here is my model:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.ProjectAssets = new List<ProjectAsset>();
    }

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectAsset> ProjectAssets { get; set; }
}

public partial class Asset
{
    public Asset()
    {
        this.Revisions = new List<Revision>();
    }

    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Revision> Revisions { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProjectAsset
{
    public int MappingID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
}
```

I have already created `Project`. And if i am creating new `Asset`, then create `Project Asset` with `AssetID` from just created `Asset`, it's OK, but i have to re-fetch `Project` from DB.
I want to do it in one transaction, like that:

```
    Project.ProjectAssets.Add(new ProjectAsset(new Asset((short)type, fileName)));
    ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IPipeLine>().Update(Project);

    public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        var fqen = GetEntityName<TEntity>();

        object originalItem;
        var key = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey(fqen, entity);
        if (((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem))
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, entity);

        //DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

But after `SaveChanges` there is no record in DB, and `MappingID` still 0.
I thought that `ApplyCurrentValues` must work with `Navigation Properties`.
Is there any good way to solve that problem?

**EDIT:**

I accessing `DAL` through`Business Entities` with contain the same properties, but they also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and other `WPF` stuff. So i think i can subscribe to `CollectionChanged` event and manualy create/delete entities from navigation property. And in property setters i can call update, but i think it can strongly decrease perfomance.

Comment: You can create a new `ProjectAsset` and only set its `ProjectID` and `Asset` properties. You don't need the `Project` object.

Comment: @GertArnold Hi, yes, i know. But i need to get project from db again or update navigation property menualy then. Also it's would be nice to do it in one operation.

Comment: In that case you must make sure that `Project.ProjectAssets` is loaded before adding items to it.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm using `DTOs`, so i can't just take `Entity` and add some `new ProjectAsset` to `Project.ProjectAssets`, i'm sending to `service` `DTO`, map it to `Entity` and `ApplyCurrentValues` to original item.